# django redirect with full url and primary key in template

Tags: python, django, templates, url

Lets say in my form I want to redirect it with form action method with full url which contains primary key too how can I do that ?

```
<a href="some_url/{}".format(detail.id)>
```

Here detail is context object name...

Its not working.. How can I redirect it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="some_url/{{ detail.id }}">
```

But it is a bad practice.  You should use the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag whenever it possible.